# How to find the expression for the original function given its inverse?

Tags: functions

How can I find the expression for the function given its inverse?

I took an example from the stereographic projection:

The stereographic projection $\pi:S^2\backslash\{N\}\to\mathbb{R}^2$, where $S^2$ is the sphere given by $x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=1$ and $N$ is the northpole $(0,0,2)$.

Let $(u,v)=\pi(x,y,z)$. The inverse map of the stereographic projection $\pi^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^2\to S^2$ is given by

$\pi^{-1}\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             x=\frac{4u}{u^2+v^2+4} \\
             y=\frac{4v}{u^2+v^2+4} \\
             z=\frac{2(u^2+v^2)}{u^2+v^2+4} 
             \end{array}
   \right.$

I would like to find the expression for $\pi$ such that we can get $u$ and $v$, from $x,y,z$.

Maybe it just involves some algebraic manipulation, but I struggle to get $u$ and $v$ from $x,y,z$ since it involves 3 equations.

Could somebody please give some hints? Many many thanks.